# Grails PayPal plugin response notification

Tags: grails, paypal, grails-plugin

I have been trying to integrate PayPal payment with a test application I am developing. If successful, I am thinking of leveraging this on my other projects.

So far, I have been able to add the plugin, configure it for Test environment and able to complete a transaction end to end. However, I have a small issue that I want some help or clarification about. Please follow the series of images below for more details:

**Button on merchant application (grails application)**

[image]

**Payment page on PayPal test site**

[image]

**Here is the paypal confirmation page for transaction:**

[image]

After making the payment above, I got a successful message on paypal test site. But when I check the logs and database, there is no notification sent to the grails application at this stage. The payment transaction is still in PENDING state:

[image]

[image]

Now, when I click on the "Return to merchant" link on the paypal confirmation page, then I redirected to my grails application with a SUCCESS message:

[image]

[image]

So, the PayPal "SUCCESS" response is sent to the grails/merchant application only after the user hits that link "Return to merchant site". In real life, the users might not want to return to the merchant site everytime. Seeing the confirmation message on PayPal site, they might assume that the transaction is done and may be PayPal does the payment too. But, how do we let the merchant site i.e the grails application know that the PayPal has already shown the user a confirmation message? So that, the user doesn't have to return to merchant site after seeing the Successful message?

**UPDATE:**
I have tried the IPN simulator upon your advice. I am not quite sure and able to understand how I can send an IPN message to my localhost application. When I tried giving my localhost or 127.0.0.1 on the IPN simulator configuration on my sandbox account, it throws error saying unable to reach the server. I am sure many developers must have tried this using local development machine, but unable to find any resource which gives the steps to use IPN simulator or IPN sandbox response for a localhost development instancE.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot rely on PDT 
you have to use  IPN
where PayPal send a notification to a page on your website where you have to authenticate, verify several possible issues and save the transaction details

See here fore more info 
[IPN](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/products/instant-payment-notification/)

Not sure if it written at that link, but you have also to enable such function from your Paypal account indicating the target page on your website.

Comment: I have tried the IPN simulator upon your advice. I am not quite sure and able to understand how I can send an IPN message to my **localhost** application. When I tried giving my localhost or 127.0.0.1 on the IPN simulator configuration on my sandbox account, it throws error saying unable to reach the server. I am sure many developers must have tried this using local development machine, but unable to find any resource which gives the steps to use IPN simulator or IPN sandbox response for a localhost development instance.

Comment: Actually, I'm not an expert, but IMHO, no one can access to localhost except you:  127.0.0.1 is a valid IP address only within your LAN:

You have to supply to PayPal a Public IP Address.

Comment: Yeah. That's what I too thought and I don't want to take the headache of opening my machine for public access either. There must be a way other developers did this. I think I will just try to fake an IPN simulator message myself using a Chrome extension or something. Thank you for the response though. I will 'up' your answer :)

Comment: well, this can be a solution, but will not allow you to make full tests:
the first step of authentication process requires you, once received the IPN Notification to send it back to PayPal asking to validate: clearly some fields cannot be simulated.
Beside this, if you need some sample messages. I think I should have some somewhere..

Comment: I found the solution. I finally managed to use the IPN Simulator with my localhost. I found this amazing tool online through some other stackoverflow posts ... https://ngrok.com/ and it does the magic of providing public access URLs (both http and https) to the local servers, and we can also give the port number to which we are looking for public access.